# Open cart: does not show view

Tags: php, opencart

I have some problem with Open cart;

Desc: I create Controller, View, Model name of calculator with names and classes.

Controller:

```
class ControllerModuleCalculator extends Controller {

    public function index() {

        $this->language->load('module/calculator');
        $this->data['someVariable'] = "Some Data";

        $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/calculator.tpl');

        $this->render();
    }
```

View:

```
<h2>Calculator View</h2>

<?php
    print $someVariable;
?>
```

Problem:
go to: localhost/?route=module/calculator, nothing to show, only white screen.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Turn ON error display and check again. Also check the error log.

Comment: use the following code to show error. `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', '1');` maybe router did not reach the controller. And which version is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lays in your controller.

Instead of

```php
$this->render();
```

you have to call

```php
$this->response->setOutput($this->render());
```

as `$this->render()` only renders the view (in OpenCart it means that the variables are being transparent for the template) but `$this->response->setOutput();` makes sure that the rendered template is displayed to the user (returned to the browser) within the HTTP response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this->

Go to admin panel and choose `Setting->User Groups->Administrator` and check `Access Permission:` for your module calculator checked or not if not checked and update.

Comment: Thank you, but when i add code to Controller;
For example:

echo "Test";


I get the message.

Comment: This answer could be helpful if the problem would be in admin area (administration). And also only if the new module would check for user's permissions. None of this is the case as we are on frontend...